# How can I set custom units in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mobile, android, units

How can I set custom units in Photoshop?

For example I want to see all distances in dp, where

```
100.00dp = 150.00px
```

I've tried to set it in `Edit -> Preferences -> Unit & Rulers`, but there I could set only predefined units.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware that you can, however you could always set a grid in the preferences to 150px with 10 subdivisions.

[image]

Then turn your grid on with **CTRL** or **CMD + '**

[image]